# CPU Overheating instantly

Tags: cpu, overheating, cpu-cooler

I was typically using my PC as i would normally do, when everything started lagging. After some reboots I decided to check on the BIOS. It was then, when I realised the temperature was too high.. So like I waited for it a bit to cool down and turned it on again.. the temperature started at 36℃ and was gradually rising and within like 15 seconds it reached 88℃ where it stopped (All of this happening while launching into BIOS, nothing, much cpu requiring task).. After reading some related threads, I tried to dust clean my liquid cooler ( CM Nepton 240M.. ) .. there was no difference.. I tried to unplug all the power source for a night and there was still no difference and finally I wanted to see how it does without the liquid cooler so I removed it, cleaned up the paste, and let it do it's best with just the fan airflow.. is started once again around 35℃ and then in just 5 seconds it reached 88℃... 
The CPU I am using is intel i5 4690k, not overcloacked or anything, I even restored the defaults on BIOS..
On a MB Asus Maximus VII ranger.. 
The airflow is alright and stuff, I've been using this PC the past 3 years on a lot of cpu demanding processes and this is the first time something like this happens.. I did update the BIOS yesterday and I have been dust cleaning it regularly, last time being two weeks ago.. 
I am using ubuntu 19.04 as an OS.. (if this makes a difference) 
How to fix the overheating?

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: Sounds like your cooler has failed.

Comment: You turned on your PC without a heatsink?  Sounds like your AIO needs to be replaced.  You have a processor that was sold 5+ years ago.  The lifespan of an AIO isn’t infinite.  Don’t run your PC within a heatsink/fan or an AIO

Comment: Had a similiar problem this week with a pc, the temperature ran above 120℃ seconds after launching a browser. Check if your thermal paste is okay, if not then start with applying a new one.

Comment: I am going to try putting a new thermal paste.. I tried to see if anything changes if I used the factory cooler my cpu came with (which i havent used for more than a week in total), though without a thermal paste.. and it had the same results. I will try some new thermal paste before trying anything else.

Comment: Update, I added some new thermal paste.. It's still pretty much the same.. The only difference is that the temperature raises slower.. The temperature gets over 80 on bios..